# Grouping null values as match with non-value fields for checking duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization, null

I'm trying to improve/optimize my query for checking duplicates in my table TABLE1.
The main requirement is to consider null value as a wildcard.

So given this table below:

[image]

Considering the null fields as a wildcard, where for example  'A' = null is true. The expected result is the record details of each record in the group and also with the group identifier which is the id and id1 on the right most side of the table:

[image]

Which is already achieved using this query:

```
WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT t1.id, t2.id as id1 FROM TABLE1 t1
             INNER JOIN TABLE1 t2 
                ON (t1.column1 = t2.column1 OR (t1.column1 IS NULL OR t2.column1 IS NULL))
                AND (t1.column2 = t2.column2 OR (t1.column2 IS NULL OR t2.column2 IS NULL))
                AND (t1.column3 = t2.column3 OR (t1.column3 IS NULL OR t2.column3 IS NULL))
                AND (t1.column4 = t2.column4 OR (t1.column4 IS NULL OR t2.column4 IS NULL))
                AND (t1.column5 = t2.column5 OR (t1.column5 IS NULL OR t2.column5 IS NULL))
                AND (t1.column6 = t2.column6 OR (t1.column6 IS NULL OR t2.column6 IS NULL))
        WHERE t2.id > t1.id)
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE1 t1
        INNER JOIN CTE C
        ON t1.id = c.id
        OR t1.id = c.id1
```

I'm also using an index containing Id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, and column6.
The query runs okay for small table, but when I run it with millions of data it runs forever.

I tried using joins and isnull but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you reach to the expected result? It's not very clear why you expect that result.

Comment: @RohitJain I wanted to consider the null fields as a wildcard, where for example  'A' = null is true. The expected result is the record details of each record in the group and also with the group identifier which is the id and id1 on the right most side of the table.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) I get `id`, but I don't understand `id1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated my tag, thanks! and id1 is for the matching row that matches with id. What I was trying to do is to have some kind of a tell which pairs goes together

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using is not compatible for using big data. I'd suggest to simplify your code.

Comment: yeah, I agree. Unfortunately nothing I tried seems to improve the performance. Do you recommend an approach for simplifying the grouping of non-null fields to null fields (as wildcard)?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following (in MySQL, if it matters)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,col1 CHAR(1) NULL
,col2 CHAR(1) NULL
,col3 CHAR(1) NULL
);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,'A','B',NULL),
 (2,'A',NULL,'C');

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 | A    | B    | NULL |
|  2 | A    | NULL | C    |
+----+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT a.*
     , b.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id, 'c1' col, col1 val FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT id, 'c2', col2 FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT id, 'c3', col3 FROM my_table
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id, 'c1' col, col1 val FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT id, 'c2', col2 FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT id, 'c3', col3 FROM my_table
     ) b
    ON b.id > a.id
   AND b.col = a.col
   AND (b.val = a.val OR b.val IS NULL or a.val IS NULL);

   +----+-----+------+----+-----+------+
   | id | col | val  | id | col | val  |
   +----+-----+------+----+-----+------+
   |  1 | c1  | A    |  2 | c1  | A    |
   |  1 | c2  | B    |  2 | c2  | NULL |
   |  1 | c3  | NULL |  2 | c3  | C    |
   +----+-----+------+----+-----+------+
```

Comment: I might be missing something so please correct me, but the result isn't the same as what i was expecting

Comment: It kind of is though. Id 1 in table a has 3 rows. Id 2 in table b has 3 corresponding rows, so it's a match; I've just left a part out as an exercise for the reader. Hopefully, you can see that if you stored the data as per 'a' (or 'b') above, it might simplify your problem.

Comment: hmm, I was trying the union approach, but I have a different data types

Comment: Ah, well that's more tricky. In that case, your approach seems reasonable. Id is PRIMARY so there's no point specifying it as part of the index (except at the end of the index - but in an InnoDB table, this is automatic)